# OLAP cube data to dataTable in c#

Tags: ado.net, ssas, olap-cube

I want to get the ssas cube data in c# datatable or dataset.So that I can use it further in pivotgrid.
So can anybody tell me how I can implement this?

Answer (score 0):

You can create an `OleDbConnection` using System.Data.OleDb, give this and some MDX to an `OleDbCommand` then pass this command to an `OleDbDataAdapter` and use it to `Fill` a `DataSet`.

Please see here for the format of the OLAP OLEDB connection strings: https://www.connectionstrings.com/microsoft-ole-db-provider-for-olap/

Note that you may also be able to achieve what you want using [ADOMD.NET](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms123483%28v=sql.110%29.aspx). This does require integrated authentication, whereas OLEDB allows you to specify the username and password. As a final aside, I think the best practice these days is to try and connect via HTTPS.